# Size of KL-divergence neighbourhoods

Tags: pr.probability, st.statistics, it.information-theory

I am new here. I was reading another
[post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/146878/set-of-distributions-that-minimize-kl-divergence)
 here and this got me wondering what can be said about the size of the following kl divergence neighborhoods.
Consider these two kl-divergence neighbourhood for a fixed distribution $P'$ and some $\alpha \geq 0$
$$ 
\mathbf{P} = \{P : D_{KL}(P||P') < \alpha\}\\ 
\mathbf{Q} = \{Q : D_{KL}(P'||Q) < \alpha\}
$$

I am wondering anything can be said about $|\mathbf{P
}|$ and $
|\mathbf{
Q}|$. Because the KL-divergence is asymmetric, I doubt they are not equal and the answer seems to be dependent on $P'$. When $\alpha=0$, the problem is trivial. I am curious about when $\alpha > 0$.
I hope this question made sense.  Thanks.

Comment: Note that Pinsker's inequality bounds KL from below by the square of the total variation distance. This gives a bound which is similar for $\mathbf{P}$ and $\mathbf{Q}$.

Comment: What is meant by $|\mathbf P|$? The cardinality (this I assumed in my answer below), or the 'size' of a 'supremal' element in $\mathbf P$ (this would require a precise definition)?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps more a question for math.stackexchange.com.

Unless your probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal F)$ is trivial (i.e. $\mathcal F = \{ \emptyset, \Omega \})$, the sets $\mathbf P$ and $\mathbf Q$ will contain a continuum of probability distributions. (Consider probability measures of the form $\frac{d P}{dP'} =\exp(-X)/E [\exp(-X)]$ for random variables $X$. Not all random variables $X$ will work, but at least uncountably many).